# Javascript Disable form field element by id (id is an array)

Tags: javascript

I am building a recurring events module to drop into a form, this module has several fields.

I have named and ID'd each of this module using array notation. EG:

```
 id='recurring_event_options[yearly][by_date_day_number]'
```

In my JS I need to target all fields with the matching id `recurring_event_options`

I have some JS working nicely that enables (non disabled) fields as needed, but before i run this i need to disable all the fields in this module.

I have been using somthing similar to this to disable the fields:

```
function disableForm(theform) {
        if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
            for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
            var formElement = theform.elements[i];
                if (true) {
                    formElement.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, that going to hit every field in the form - thats not what i want - only to disable the fields that belong to the `recurring_event_options` parent ID.

I have a feeling I probably cant use [] notation in IDs, so suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think it is not a good idea to use `[]`.
You can use a hyphen `-` or underscore `_` to separate the values:

```
id='recurring_event_options-yearly-by_date_day_number'
```

Now you can disable:

```
function disableForm(theform) {
    for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
        var formElement = theform.elements[i];
        if (formElement.id.indexOf("recurring_event_options") !== -1) {
            formElement.disabled = true;
        }
     }
}
```

This should work. but in my opinion it will be much better if you use a class instead:

```
<input type="text" class="recurring_event_options prop2 prop3" />
```

because the class attribute is designed to support multiple values, separated by a space